# Ускорение выгрузки данных из mysql для высоконагруженных приложений

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, highload

Столкнулся с проблемой: необходимо выгружать за приемлемое время в csv большой объем данных из базы MySQL (десятки миллионов записей). Запрос содержит большое количество колонок для выгрузки с кучей джойнов и преобразований данных. Что было уже сделано для ускорения:

1. Расставлены все индексы
2. Запрос переведен на небуферизированный
3. Выбрана наиболее быстрая библиотека для выгрузки в csv

Все равно на больших объемах данных выгрузка происходит очень долго (со стороны БД). Хотелось бы узнать, что еще можно сделать для ускорения? В какую сторону можно покопать?

Думал в сторону разработки ETL, которая бы взяла на себя часть преобразования данных и записывала их в удобный для последующей выгрузки формат (сокращая в том числе кол-во join). Но с ходу не нашел полезных статей и подходящего формата (бд) для хранения

Comment: Чтобы понять, что можно сделать для ускорения, нужно сперва понять, что тормозит. «Очень долго» это слишком абстрактно, нужно помониторить, попрофилировать и так далее. В конце концов может оказаться, что нужно тупо купить сервер помощнее и поместить базу на SSD

Comment: *Запрос переведен на небуферизированный .. Выбрана наиболее быстрая библиотека для выгрузки в csv* Вот поневоле вопрос - а для чего с этом супе что-либо, кроме самого MySQL? `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` сам прекрасно справится с выгрузкой в CSV. Привлечение к этому процессу PHP (для прочих, кроме собственно передачи на MySQL запроса, действий) - это дополнительная и никому не нужная гиря на ноге...

Comment: @Akina Увы, на уровне кода тоже выполняется часть дополнительных вычислений, которые затем пишутся в csv. Их не сделать на уровне БД.